# Why is the DateTime tryparse failing for the date 20140404

Tags: c#, datetime

I wrote a simple unit test that fails when trying to parse the date "20140404".

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse("20140404", out dt);
Assert.IsTrue(dt.Year == 2014 && dt.Month == 4 && dt.Day == 4);
```

Can someone clear this up for me, should I be passing in the expected format?

On my webpage form, I said I want users to enter the format yyyymmdd.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply the format in `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact("20140404",
                       "yyyyMMdd",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt);
```

You can also validate if the parsing was successful or not

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("20140404",
    "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt))
{
    //parsing successfull
}
else
{
    //parsing failed
}
```

`TryParse` group of methods returns a boolean value indicating if parsing was successful or not. When the parsing fails it returns `false` instead of raising an exception and the `out` variables is assigned the default value. That is why your Test is failing, since `dt` was assigned the default value `dt = {01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}`.

Why parsing with `TryParse` was failing in your case? , because `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse` use already defined date formats in [DateTimeFormatInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Your format is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to specify a custom format string and use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                            "20140404", 
                            "yyyyMMdd", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, 
                            out dt);

// Check success
```

If you're going to ignore the return value, you'd be better off using `ParseExact` instead of `TryParseExact`, as you'd get an exception in that case if you feed bad data.

Answer (score 1):

As to why it doesn't work: `DateTime.TryParse` iterates over the standard formats inside `DateTimeFormatInfo` and this isn't among the list.

You can verify this by executing

```
new DateTimeFormatInfo().GetAllDateTimePatterns().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

If you don't want to use `ParseExact`, you can add your own formats to this collection using [`SetAllDatePatterns()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.setalldatetimepatterns(v=vs.110).aspx).